# Run-time Error 2498 for Append and Make Table Queries Created in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm getting a 2498 error and really don't understand why.  I'm building a string in VBA and am getting the error with the following line of code...

DoCmd.OpenQuery qdfNew, acNormal

It happened with a very long string created to create the query so I simplified the code as much as possible and am still getting the error.

Here's the code...

---

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit
Dim dbsFootball As Database
Dim strInsertSQL, strSelectSQL, strIntoSQL, strFromSQL, strOrderSQL, strSQL As String
Dim qdfNew As QueryDef
```

---

```
Sub CreateFormattedData()

Set dbsFootball = CurrentDb()
strSelectSQL = ""
strIntoSQL = ""
strFromSQL = ""
strOrderSQL = ""
strSQL = ""

strSelectSQL = "SELECT [tbl_Raw_League_Data].[Season]"
strIntoSQL = "INTO [tbl_Manip Data]"
strFromSQL = "FROM [tbl_Raw_League_Data]" _
    + "LEFT JOIN Referees ON [tbl_Raw_League_Data].[Referee] = Referees.[Referee from Source Data]"
strSQL = strSelectSQL + " " + strIntoSQL + " " + strFromSQL + " " + strOrderSQL
On Error Resume Next                    ' If query doesn't exist, error won't stop execution
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "pgmqry_Create Table tbl_Manip"
On Error GoTo 0                         ' Reset error handler
Set qdfNew = dbsFootball.CreateQueryDef("pgmqry_Create Table tbl_Manip", strSQL)
DoCmd.OpenQuery qdfNew, acNormal

End Sub
```

---

The source field, [tbl_Raw_League_Data].[Season], is a "Short Text" data type (field size = 7).

If I terminate the VBA code and run the query that was created by the code, it works fine with no apparent errors.  However, it will never run the query from within the VBA code.

I was originally getting the error 2498 when using "INSERT INTO" for an append query, but realized that the table could as easily be recreated at code execution time.

I'm lost and would sure appreciate some ideas!

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the querydef object to `DoCmd.OpenQuery` when it expects a string referencing name of a stored query object. Consider using the querydef's `Name` property:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery qdfNew.Name, acNormal
```

Alternatively, use `.Execute` command from database object using the SQL string variable, bypassing any need for querydef:

```
dbsFootball.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Or with querydef object, as @HansUp suggests, where you simply execute directly since it is an action query:

```
qdfNew.Execute dbFailOnError
```

Do note above two options bring up the regular MS Access discussion, of using [stored vs VBA string query](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&redir_esc=&client=tablet-android-google&source=android-browser-type&v=141255454&qsubts=1464390310903&q=stored+vs+vba+query). While the former is precompiled and runs through query optimizer caching best plan, the latter can have sql dynamically created (structural components that is like `SELECT`, `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses as both can use passed in parameters). From your code snippet consider saving SQL query beforehand without needing to build it in VBA on the fly, and call it with `DoCmd.OpenQuery`.

Comment: Parfait, thank you very much for the help.  This is the first time I've come across the .Execute and it works like a champ!